# Convert RGBA-image to black and white image in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

**tf.image.decode_png()** can output grayscale, RGB and RGBA image.

But I'd like to convert RGBA to pure black and white in **Tensorflow** (without using **pillow**).

Please give me some advice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `tf.select` to do the thresholding

```
pil_image = PilImage.open('/temp/panda.png')
show_pil_image(pil_image)
```

[image]

```
pil_buf = open('/temp/panda.png').read()
contents = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.string)
decode_op = tf.image.decode_png(contents, channels=1)
gray_image = tf.squeeze(decode_op) # shape (127,127,1) -> shape (127,127)
sess = create_session()
[decoded] = sess.run([gray_image], feed_dict={contents: pil_buf})
show_pil_image(PilImage.fromarray(decoded))
```

[image]

```
contents = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.string)
decode_op = tf.image.decode_png(contents, channels=1)
gray_image = tf.squeeze(decode_op) # shape (127,127,1) -> shape (127,127)
select_op = tf.select(gray_image>127, 255*tf.ones_like(gray_image), tf.zeros_like(gray_image))
sess = create_session()
[decoded] = sess.run([select_op], feed_dict={contents: pil_buf})
show_pil_image(PilImage.fromarray(decoded))
```

[image]

Comment: Use `tf.where` in place of `tf.select` for TensorFlow >= v1.0 https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/where