# with tensorflow, image buffer not corresponding to model

Tags: tensor, tensorflow.js

I try to train model with images.
My model is based on :

```
_myModel = _tf.sequential();
_myModel.add(_tf.layers.conv2d({ inputShape: [96, 96, 1],....
```

Each image for train is loaded with...

```
let buffer = _fs.readFileSync(filePath);
let imageTensor = _tfnode.node.decodeImage( buffer, <channels>)
    .resizeNearestNeighbor([96,96])
```

and the whole set of tensors are used to train the model:

```
_myModel.fit( trainData.images, trainData.labels, ...
```

Here are the differents errors with each value of "channels" :

No "channels" value (default is 0):

```
let imageTensor = _tfnode.node.decodeImage( buffer)...
_myModel.fit( trainData.images, trainData.labels, {...
 err: Error: input expected a batch of elements where each example has shape [96,96,1] (i.e.,tensor shape [*,96,96,1]) but the input received an input with 7 examples, each with shape [96,96,4] (tensor shape [7,96,96,4])
```

With "channels" = 1 (B&W) :

```
let imageTensor = _tfnode.node.decodeImage( buffer, 1)...
_myModel.fit( trainData.images, trainData.labels, {...
err: Error: target expected a batch of elements where each example has shape [5] (i.e.,tensor shape [*,5]) but the target received an input with 7 examples, each with shape [7] (tensor shape [7,7])
```

With "channels" = 3 (RGB) :

```
let imageTensor = _tfnode.node.decodeImage( buffer, 3)...
_myModel.fit( trainData.images, trainData.labels, {....
err: Error: input expected a batch of elements where each example has shape [96,96,1] (i.e.,tensor shape [*,96,96,1]) but the input received an input with 7 examples, each with shape [96,96,3] (tensor shape [7,96,96,3])
```

So, how to match image tensor with model ?

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

your model definition specifies what looks like grayscale single-channel input:

```js
_myModel.add(_tf.layers.conv2d({ inputShape: [96, 96, 1],....
```

so you need to convert your `imageTensor` to that.
right now you've tried with RGBA (4-channels) and RGB (3-channels) - and neither are what model definition states.

something like

```js
const rgb = [0.2989, 0.5870, 0.1140]; // factors for red/green/blue colors when converting to grayscale: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rgb2gray.html
const [red, green, blue] = tf.split(imageTensor, 3, 3);
const redNorm = tf.mul(red, rgb[0]);
const greenNorm = tf.mul(green, rgb[1]);
const blueNorm = tf.mul(blue, rgb[2]);
const grayscale = tf.addN([redNorm, greenNorm, blueNorm]);
```

Comment: Hello, It is the reason why i have tried "let imageTensor = _tfnode.node.decodeImage( buffer, 1)" , which is the same as "decode_op = tf.image.decode_png(contents, channels=1)" (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35836326/convert-rgba-image-to-black-and-white-image-in-tensorflow). But it fails.